# Failed to start Git process

Tags: git, phpstorm, bitbucket

I tried to push to Bitbucket with PhpStorm but is send to me an error message like this: `Failed to start Git process`. Yesterday it worked but now something is wrong. What can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like your system (or you) updated the Git executable and PhpStorm is now unable to locate or access it. I also got the same error after updating Git while PhpStorm tried to show the version history.

Your Git settings inside PhpStorm should look similar to this:

[image: PhpStorm git settings]

As you can see, the path to the Git executable is `/use/local/bin/git` which should be standard for all Unix-based systems. Please verify, that there is an executable in the field. If yes, click the test button and PhpStorm will tell you what's wrong with the file.

Also try to clear the caches and restart PhpStorm with the `Invalidate Caches/Restart` option under the File menu.

Comment: I've had the same issue with IntelliJ and the hint regarding Git's executable path did the trick. Don't forget to restart your IDE, because it seems like it keeps the old path in memory.