# PyCharm fails to start git process

Tags: git, pycharm

Since applying the Windows 10 anniversary update, Pycharm (2016.2.3) cannot complete any git commands using the GUI. Fetch, pull, commit, etc. all throw an error "Failed to start Git process". The same commands typed into the terminal within PyCharm run without any issue. Here are my Pycharm Git settings:

[image: PyCharm git settings]

Testing the path to the Git executable appears to work correctly. Re-installing both PyCharm and git has not helped. As per this answer: [Failed to start Git process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38479497/failed-to-start-git-process) I have tried clearing the cache and restarting to no avail.

Comment: After it happened, click on the status line to show the event log and see if something is there and also look in the lower right corner of the IDE if there is a red bubble showing errors and finally got to `Help -> Show Log in Explorer` and review the `idea.log` for errors. If any of these locations shows more helpful info and you are not able to resolve it yet, post it here. If this also helped, tell me, then I make my comment an answer for you to accept it.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realise i could see such a log. I found this error: INFO - llij.util.net.HttpConfigurable - C:\Users\Nicholas\.PyCharm2016.2\config\options\proxy.settings.pwd (Access is denied). So i reinstalled PyCharm not importing the previous settings, which has fixed the issue

Comment: Ok, I made my comment an answer for you to accept. But it would proabably have been enough to grant file-system access to the file in question or delete it or delete `C:\Users\Nicholas\.PyCharm2016.2`, no need to uninstall and reinstall the whole program, but works that way too of course, just a bit too much work done. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After it happened, click on the status line to show the event log and see if something is there and also look in the lower right corner of the IDE if there is a red bubble showing errors and finally got to Help -> Show Log in Explorer and review the idea.log for errors. If any of these locations shows more helpful info and you are not able to resolve it yet, post it here.