# GIT - IntelliJ : Failed to start Git process

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I m getting this message when I try to pull or to push my commits using IntelliJ :

> "Failed to start Git process"

In the settings of my IntelliJ I linked the git binary folder as this : C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe and when I click on "Test" it says the following :

> Git executed successfully Git version is 2.9.0

However when I use the command line (using a terminal) to pull aord push it works correctly!

I consulted several links on the web to resolve my issue but without success I consulted this one too : [Failed to start Git process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38479497/failed-to-start-git-process)

Comment: Is it possible to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Answer (score 7):

Had a similar issue. In my case, IntelliJ logs(C:\Users\UserName\.IdeaIC2017.3\system\log) had the following info:

"C:\Users\UserName\.IdeaIC2017.3\system\tmp\intellij-git-askpass.bat (Access is denied)"

So, I went ahead and deleted the following two files(located at C:\Users\UserName\.IdeaIC2017.3\system\tmp) and the error went away:

intellij-git-askpass.bat

intellij-git-ssh.bat

Not really sure what the two files are responsible for, though.

Answer (score 4):

Go to `preferences => Version control => Git` Change the directory path for the executable to `/usr/local/git/bin/git`.

Hit Test button to confirm.

Comment: Tried upgrading Xcode, xcodebuild blah di blah, didn't realise it was as simple as this solution here, spot on

Answer (score 0):

The simple ways is to try the following steps:

First run :

```
$ git config --global credential.helper store
```

Then simply Update your git version :

```
$git update-git-for-windows
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (ubuntu 20.04) I had to change how I was starting up intellij

`/snap/intellij-idea-community/current/bin/idea.sh &`

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted two files from  below location. It worked for me.

C:\Users\Your User name\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2020.1\tmp

1. intellij-git-askpass.bat
2. intellij-git-ssh.bat

After deleting these two files, go to Intellij--> File---> select "Invalidate Caches/ Restart" option---> click on "Invalidate and Restart"

After restarting Intellij, error will remove.